# Automatically scale up iPad Air images to fit iPad Pro?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, cocoa-touch

Is there a way to tell Xcode to scale up my app so it fits an iPad Pro? Or do I have to do this manually in the code? I do have a launch image file and it scales up the launch image, but nothing else.

Comment: You have to use a launch screen file to get your app to fully use the iPad Pro screen size.

Comment: @rmaddy I do have a launch image xib and it scales up the launch image just fine. But it lays out the rest of the app as if it's an iPad Air. Am I missing something? Or I should say, it is using the iPad Pro screen size, but I'd prefer if it just scaled up my app (like how it scales down the app to fit on an iPad mini).

Comment: What is a launch image xib? You need a Launch Screen file (storyboard) for the iPad Pro.

Comment: @rmaddy it's an alternative to a storyboard, you can do a xib or storyboard for the launch screen file.

Comment: I have answered it here. Hope this helps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39729390/ipad-pro-scale-up-from-ipad-application-and-launch-screen-file-ios-10/42637154#42637154

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this is: no, there is no way to tell the app to automatically scale up iPad images for use on the iPad Pro. I imagine Apple wants developers to avoid doing this and force them to create images that are the correct resolution.