# iPad Pro scale up from iPad application and Launch Screen file - iOS 10

Tags: ios, ipad, cocoa-touch, ios10, xcode8

I have an ipad application that I would like to run on iPad pro, but when I run it, it only occupies one corner of the screen like so:

[image]

Now, another stackoverflow question asked the same question and the response was to remove the launch screen file and not to give the OS any hardcoded information about the device size it's going to run on. I did it and it scaled my app to full screen BUT..

It created another iOS10 specific bug that happens if you don't specify the launch screen: 
[iPad Application shows app icon as launch screen in iOS 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39571694/ipad-application-shows-app-icon-as-launch-screen-in-ios-10)

How can I fix this without compromising on one bug or the other.

Comment: Since `XCode` now provides the `iPad Pro Sceen` in the `Launch Screen.storyboard` file, just check once if the view is proper.

Comment: Do you want to take full advantage of the iPad Pro's larger screen or do you simply want regular iPad sized app to be scaled up to fill the larger screen (you should answer yes for your users' sakes)?

Comment: @rmaddy I want to scale it up for now before working on the full size layout for the Pro.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into similar issue. Below is the solution that worked for me.

My app uses a launch story board to fix the weird issue of zoomed app icon on launch.

Removing this resulted in fixing the resolution in iPad Pro and app behaved exactly like in iPad Air.

But i need to add Launch image to fix the zoomed app icon on launch. 
Go to Setting -> General

[Launch image settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYVP0.png)

[Add launch images (1024 * 768) in asset catalog. (Based on orientations your app supports.)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kiZki.png)

This should fix both the issues of zoomed app icon on launch and setting proper resolution to fit the app in iPad Pro as in iPad Air.